# Typescript: What is the difference between if(variable), if(!variable) and if(!!variable)?

Tags: typescript

In typescript, what is the difference between

```
if (x)
```

```
if (!x)
```

```
if (!!x)
```

Could this have different behaviors depends on the type of variable? (string, number, object, etc...).
What I mean with the sentence above is:

```
const myString = 'hello';
const myObject = new MyClass(10, 'Luke');
const ten = 10;

if(myString) 
if(!myString)
if(!!myString)

if(myObject)
if(!myObject)
if(!!myObject)

if(ten)
if(!ten)
if(!!ten)
```

In this example, when the code enters in one if instead of another?

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript has nothing to do with it, it's javascript.

[if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

> The if statement executes a statement if a specified condition is
> truthy. If the condition is falsy, another statement can be executed.

- `!` - logical not operator, can convert value to inverted boolean
- `!!` - convert value to boolean (analog [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean))

falsy values: number `0`, BigInt `0n`, `null`, `undefined`, boolean `false`, number `NaN`, string `''`

```js
const myString = 'hello';
const myObject = { test: 123 };
const ten = 10;

console.log(myString);
console.log(!myString);
console.log(!!myString, Boolean(myString));

console.log(myObject);
console.log(!myObject);
console.log(!!myObject, Boolean(myObject));

console.log(ten);
console.log(!ten);
console.log(!!ten, Boolean(ten));
```